# Add UIViewController to UIScrollView swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm working on a `ScrollView`. Currently I have tow images in my ScrollView and I want to add at least a new `UIViewController` in the `ScrollView`.

That is the code which I have yet:

```
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    let scrollviewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    let scrollviewWidth = self.scrollView.frame.width

    var imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    var imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))

    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "preview1")
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "preview2")

    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.width * 2, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

Design:

[The first one is the root ViewController, where the ScrollView is and the second one I want to add in the ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTKQf.png)

Comment: Where is UIViewController in this code

Comment: @Krunal I do not have yet added a new UIViewController because Idk if and how its possible. Should I do it with a `@IBOutlet` ?

Comment: It is possible to do that, just let me know, where do you want to add it. Share your design.

Comment: I like to add the new `UIViewController` after the `imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "preview1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and see:

```
self.scrollView.frame = CGRect( <set frame> )

var imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect( <set frame> ))
var imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect( <set frame> ))
var vcView = UIView(frame: CGRect( <set frame> ))
addChildVC(vcView: vcView)

imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "preview1")
imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "preview2")

self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vcView)



self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize( <set content size> )
self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

Add child view Controller

```
func addChildVC(vcView: UIView){

let testVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testIdentifier") as! TestViewController
    testVC.view.frame = vcView.bounds
    vcView.addSubview(testVC.view)
    self.addChildViewController(testVC)
    testVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```